# Build Shapely point objects from .TIF

Tags: python, gdal, geopandas, shapely, rasterio

I would like to convert an image (.tiff) into Shapely points. There are 45 million pixels, I need a way to accomplish this without a loop (currently taking 15+ hours)

For example, I have a .tiff file which when opened is a 5000x9000 array. The values are pixel values (colors) that range from 1 to 215.
I open tif with `rasterio.open(xxxx.tif)`.
Desired epsg is 32615

I need to preserve the pixel value but also attach geospatial positioning. This is to be able to sjoin over a polygon to see if the points are inside. I can handle the transform after processing, but I cannot figure a way to accomplish this without a loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a boolean array indicating whether the points are within *any* of the geometries, I'd dissolve the shapes into a single MultiPolygon then use [`shapely.vectorized.contains`](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/blob/main/shapely/vectorized/__init__.py#L22). The `shapely.vectorized` module is currently not covered in the documentation, but it's really good to know about!

Something along the lines of

```py
# for a gridded dataset with 2-D arrays lats, lons
# and a list of shapely polygons/multipolygons all_shapes

XX = lons.ravel()
YY = lats.ravel()

single_multipolygon = shapely.ops.unary_union(all_shapes)

in_any_shape = shapely.vectorized.contains(single_multipolygon, XX, YY)
```

If you're looking to identify *which* shape the points are in, use [`geopandas.points_from_xy`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.points_from_xy.html) to convert your x, y point coordinates into a GeometryArray, then use [`geopandas.sjoin`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html) to find the index of the shape corresponding to each (x, y) point:

```py
geoarray = geopandas.points_from_xy(XX, YY)
points_gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geoarray)

shapes_gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=all_shapes)

shape_index_by_point = geopandas.sjoin(
    shapes_gdf, points_gdf, how='right', predicate='contains',
)
```

This is still a large operation, but it's vectorized and will be significantly faster than a looped solution. The geopandas route is also a good option if you'd like to convert the projection of your data or use other geopandas functionality.

Comment: Just the solution I was looking for, many thanks!